# How to rotate column in grid of doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, nodes

If I had a grid made of double linked lists, ie each node has 4 pointers, left, right up and down. How would I rotate a column ie;
in grid

```
    A B C D


    1 2 3 4


    E F G H
```

node D has the following pointers: left = C right = A up = H and down = 4
how do I get the grid to look like:

```
    A B C 4


    1 2 3 H


    E F G D
```

after calling the rotate(3,2) function where the first argument is row and the second is number of slots downwards to rotate.

Note I am working in C++

Comment: 1) Walk down the column you are rotating. For each node, keep the left pointer, the node itself, and the right pointer. 2)  rotate the vector of pointers as desired 3) for each index i: `left[i]->right = node[i]; node[i]->left = left[i]; node[i]->right = right[i]; right[i]->left = node[i];`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like one of those trick questions in a coding interview.  Where you think you have to manage all these complex pointer relationships.  But the simpler solution is to just move the values between nodes in the list and leave the pointers between nodes as-is.  The hint is in your own description of the problem (where you said *"look like"*).

So in the case of rotating a column, you could call a function similar to the one below and pass it any item in that column.

```
// for each item in the column, copy its value to the item above it
void RotateColumn(Node* firstnode)
{
    Node* current = firstnode;
    Node* next = current->down;
    char firstvalue = current->value;
    while (next != firstnode)
    {
       current->value = next->value;
       current = next;
       next = next->down;
    }
    current->value = firstvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more thought, I came up with a way that does not require any extra storage:

- Take a node N in the given column, along with its left- and right neighbours L and R.
- Follow the `N->down` pointer k times, assign the result to N.
- Let M = N, do the following until M = N again:

  - Point `L->right` to M and `M->right` to L
  - Point `R->left` to M and `M->right` to R
  - Take the down pointer for L, M and R.

In code, that would look like this:

```
void rotate_down(Node * N, unsigned int k) {
  Node * L = N->left;
  Node * R = N->right;
  while (k-- > 0) N = N->down;
  Node * M = N;
  do {
    L->right = M; M->left = L;
    R->left = M; M->right = R;
    L = L->down; M = M->down; R = R->down;
  } while (M != N);
}
```

For extra credit, make this function generic in the movement direction via a template parameter.